# Xdebug 3.0 WSL2 and VSCode - address is already in use by docker-proxy

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug, wsl-2

My VSCode in WSL:Ubuntu is unable to listen to the xdebug port, because it is blocked by some docker-proxy.

I was following this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190658/xdebug-3-0-wsl2-and-vscode-configuration-that-works), but trying VSCode to listen to the xdebug port, results in the following error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9003

Can anyone help with connecting VSCode to xdebug?

Windows 11 says the port is already allocated by wslhost:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 9003).OwningProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    285      47     2288       4748       0,05  19480   1 wslhost
```

Ubuntu tells, its allocated by some docker-proxy:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17210/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9003                 :::*                    LISTEN      17217/docker-proxy
```

docker-compose-version: `docker-compose version 1.25.0`

The xdebug.log says:

```
[Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[Step Debug] ERR: Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
```

For sure as long as nothing is listening.

As to `xdebug.client_host` I'v tried:

- **host.docker.internal**
- **xdebug://gateway** and **xdebug://nameserver** refering to this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W-NzNtExf5C4eOu3rRQm1WlWnbW44u3ANDDA49d3FD4/edit?pli=1
- setting the env-variable with docker-compose.yml: `XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=..."`

Removing the Expose directive from Dockerfile/docker-compose as in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69845907/xdebug-tries-to-connect-to-the-wrong-address-xdebug-php-docker-vscode-wsl2) doesn't remove the error neither.

Comment: `xdebug://gateway` and `xdebug://nameserver` are not in a released version yet, so they wouldn't work :-)

Comment: 1) Restart PC, may help 2) Double check that none of the active/running Docker images have such 9003 port used or exposed by any service. 3) Shutdown images one by another while you have ZERO Docker images running -- is it still there? 4) Shutdown Docker -- is it still there? 4) Use another Xdebug port (e.g. 9004 or some another number) -- in both php.ini and VSCode ofc.

Comment: Thanks you for you help.
I removed every expose of 9003 and the php-fpm-container is the only container with port-binding `9003:9003`. If I remove it from docker-compose.yml the port is free for listening. But VSCode still did'nt catch the debug session even if I configure **xdebug.client_host** with the ip from ubuntu's **/etc/resolv.conf**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. For others with this challenge:

Inside of wsl-ubuntu -> docker-containter `host.docker.internal` directs to the wrong ip.
In the wsl-distribution the file `/etc/resolv.conf` is the ip of the windows host.
To get the correct ip use this answer: [How to get the primary IP address of the local machine on Linux and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x#answer-13322549)

My solution is to define an env-variable with this ip:

```
alias docker_compose_local_ip="ifconfig eth0 | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p'"
export DOCKER_COMPOSE_LOCAL_IP=$(docker_compose_local_ip)
```

and configure the container with it:

```
services:
  service-name:
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_CONFIG=client_host=${DOCKER_COMPOSE_LOCAL_IP} ...
```

Comment: In Xdebug 3.2 and later (not released yet), you can use `xdebug.client_host=xdebug://nameserver` to do this automatically.

Comment: this had been driving me nuts. Amazing workaround, THANK YOU!